# Get user logged into a given tty

Tags: linux, bash, regex, tty

I'm writing a bash script that disconnects idle sessions but writes to the tty a few seconds before terminating it to make sure it really is not being used.

The format for `write` is `write user [tty]`.

I'm starting with a tty string, i.e "pts/1".

I know I can find the user next to the tty name in "who" and "w", but am uncertain of how to put the username (i.e john) in a variable. Would this require a regex? I was originally looking for a single command but `who` and `w` don't have such options in their documentation.

Comment: `ttys=$(who | awk '{print $2}'); echo $ttys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. It uses `stat` to extract the username of the owner of the pseudo-tty. Here, `$pts` should be in the format in the question, eg. `pts/2`.

```
tty_user=$(stat -c%U /dev/$pts)
```